# Obsidian: How to restore the plugin icon on the top-right corner?

Tags: obsidian

I used to have Calendar plugin on the top-right of the Obsidian window.
But I accidentally closed it.

How can I restore them?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the exact calendar plugin you're using, it could differ slightly. But generally speaking, it would work like this:

Find the command in the command palette (Ctrl + P) and type "calendar". In most cases, it will give you an option like "Display calendar" or "Open calendar" or whatever the plugin was programmed to display.

It may not open directly in that top right corner panel, although it often does. But in either case you can drag that tab around into almost any part of the interface to best suit your needs.

There may also be a ribbon button (left side of interface) for your calendar plugin.

If that doesn't work I recommend looking at the plugin's settings page, and if you can't find clarification there, head over to their github page/plugin page (by going into Community Plugins and clicking on the name of the plugin itself instead of the toggle/options/hotkey button.)